# Edit jQuery-Mobile's <select> behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, onchange, stoppropagation

I have a jQuery Mobile/Cordova application and I want to *"stylize"* a select to show it like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeocW.png)

## TL;DR

I know that jQuery transforms the `<select>` in a `<div>` containing a `<span>` which takes the **text** of the selected `<option>`, so this is what you write in `<html>`:

```
<select name="date_set" form="sba-form" id="sba-dateSet">
    <option disabled selected value="null">Seleziona la Data</option>
    <option selected value="2-3-2016-3">Mer 2 Marzo, 2016</option>
    <option selected value="3-3-2016-4">Gio 3 Marzo, 2016</option>
    <option selected value="4-3-2016-5">Ven 4 Marzo, 2016</option>
</select>
```

And this is the result after the jQuery transformation:

```
<div class="ui-select">
    <div id="sba-dateSet-button" class="various-jQuery-ui-classes">
        <span>Mer 2 Marzo, 2016</span>
        <select name="date_set" form="sba-form" id="sba-dateSet">
            <option disabled selected value="null">Seleziona la Data</option>
            <option selected value="2-3-2016-3">Mer 2 Marzo, 2016</option>
            <option selected value="3-3-2016-4">Gio 3 Marzo, 2016</option>
            <option selected value="4-3-2016-5">Ven 4 Marzo, 2016</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Scenario

I tought that I could edit this behaviour applaying my style to the `<span>` using the **value** of the `<option>`  and [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/CliffBurton/yTt9b/1541/), displaying an alert at the end of the event you can see that the `<span>` gets the correct value now, this is what I've used:

```
$("#sba-dateSet").change(function(e) {
    var parent = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    var thisVal = $(this).val();
    var spltVal = thisVal.split("-");
    // Days and Months are stored in corrispondent global variables
    var selH = '';
    selH += '<div class="styledSelect day">' + spltVal[0] + '</div>';
    selH += '<div class="styledSelect rest">' + days[spltVal[3] - 1] + '<br />' + months[spltVal[1] - 1] + ', ' + spltVal[2] + '</div>';

    $("#" + parent + " span").html(selH);
    alert("It Works!");
});
```

But after you click <kbd>Ok</kbd> on the alert (after my custom event handler is finished) jQuery comes in and changes it again with its default behaviour.

## The question

How can I stop/block jQuery Mobile default behaviour or its event handler?
Even if this is not the very-default behaviour I tried `event.preventDefault()`, `event.stopPropagation()` and `return false` at the end of my custom event handler and as expected none of them worked

**Edit:** I foud that on [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CliffBurton/yTt9b/1541/) everything works correctly and the `<span>` tag remains as I want without errors in console so I tought it could be a problem related to cordova, so I made an attempt on my server (a copy-paste of the fiddle) excluding every cordova injection...but the problem is still there

Comment: exclude everything on your server and then re-include step-by-step to debug what is causing the behaviour overwrite as it is hard for us to help you because the snippet you posted works perfectly fine

Comment: This is exactly what I did @dasjanik, the attempt on my server was on a blank page on which I have copy-pasted step-by-step everything from the fiddle...isn't there anything else which can block the event propagation?

Comment: you can override select widget to add your custom code [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/widgets/forms/select.js#L240).

Comment: Llike this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2b5kp2hf/

Comment: @Omar I love you!! I think I'm going to take a more in-dept study in jQuery code to prevent another day of no success. Please post this as an answer so I can accept it